# AngularJS Directive with no Template and Sharing the updates from parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a very simple requirement where a directive is placed inside a **ng-repeat** in this I wanted to push down the changes to directive so it updates the UI. Meaning I want the value of **Contact(not just a string reference actual object)** inside my link function so I can render the UI and also change my UI when **contact** changes in the parent **ng-repeat**.

I had created a very **[simplified version](http://jsfiddle.net/NDFHg/54/)** of what I wanted to achive. It has a list of Contacts ( After researching with help of this **[link by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)** I know **ng-repeat** creates its own scope so I added an object called deep which is an object not primitive) , I am struggling to get this sorted. I also had tried to use other possible option. I dont want to paste a template in directive with **ng-show/ng-class** stuff because business logic is but tricky so it is easier to do it using link function. I am sure this has to do with **scope and/or $observe** but I dont know how to get this sorted. Also note this is a simpler version of what I wanted to achieve. I actually want value of that object to render my UI.

**[My Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NDFHg/54/)** You will see when you click on Update Name outer repeat gets updated no the inner.

```
<div>
  <div ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            <div zippy="contact">a</div>            
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <p>Here we repeat the contacts to ensure bindings work:</p>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            {{contact.name}} : {{contact.deep}}
        </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module( 'myApp', [] );
app.controller('ContactsCtrl', function ( $scope ) {      
    $scope.contacts = [
                        { name: 'Sharon',deep:{A:"a"}},
                        { name: 'Steve',deep:{A:"b"}},
                        { name: 'Scott',deep:{A:"c"}}
    ];

    $scope.primitiveTest=function(c){c.name=c.name+c.name; }    
    $scope.objectTest=function(c){c.deep={A:c.deep.A+c.deep.A};  }
});
app.directive('zippy',  ['$compile', function ($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {       

          /*scope.$watch(attrs.zippy, function(newValue, oldValue){
                alert('asd');
            });

          attrs.$observe('deep',function(val){ alert('asd'); });*/
        scope.$watch(attrs['zippy'],
             function (ideaNode) {      
                 var html = [];
                 html.push('<hr/><div class="clearfix" id="vote-icons" ng-click="primitiveTest('+attrs['zippy']+');" >Update Name </div> - <div class="clearfix" id="vote-icons" ng-click="objectTest('+attrs['zippy']+');">UpdateObject');              
                 html.push('</div>');
                 html.push(JSON.stringify(ideaNode));                
                 element.html(html.join(''));
                 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
             }
        );
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: I am curious if were able to unit test this?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the $watch in the directive if you adopt the following approach.

You should use the object interpolation `html.push("{{" + attrs['zippy'] + "}}");` instead of the serialized plain text string if you want the model to be interpolated and updated.

```
app.directive('zippy', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = [];
            html.push('<hr/><div class="clearfix" id="vote-icons" ng-click="primitiveTest(' + attrs['zippy'] + ');" >Update Name </div> - <div class="clearfix" id="vote-icons" ng-click="objectTest(' + attrs['zippy'] + ');">UpdateObject');
            html.push('</div>');
            html.push("{{" + attrs['zippy'] + "}}");
            element.html(html.join(''));
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LRjBG/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! That works . But In my actual example I need the value of attrs['zippy'] which is a multilevel object so I can render the UI based on various attributes in it. Any Idea ?

Comment: @Kusek If the object is in scope, you can try `html.push("{{" + scope[attrs['zippy']] + "}}");`